# c++ boost.thread executable not running

Tags: c++, dll, mingw, boost-thread

I'm new to c++ (but not from programing), and I wanted to create a program with thread. I installed boost (https://gist.github.com/zrsmithson/0b72e0cb58d0cb946fc48b5c88511da8) on my computer (windows), but when I run the executable the program just stop (no errors).

The program is the helloworld.cpp program inside the folder example. I think the issue is the lib (-lboost_thread-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66 -lboost_system-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66 -lboost_chrono-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66) or the compiler (MinGW).
The code:

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void helloworld()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread thrd(&helloworld);
    thrd.join();
}
```

Excuse me for my English.
Thank you in advance for your help,
Flayme

Comment: You probably did not have the required dlls in a folder of your `PATH`  environment variable or the same folder as your executable.

Comment: Your MinGW and boost are quite a few years old but that should not cause you an issue. You should update those however.

Comment: When compiling I use -L"\MinGW\lib"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by putting the library inside the folder where I compile, and then changed `-L"\MinGW\lib"` to `-L`.